# Switching between ViewControllers?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, xcode4

I have a NavigationController based app with multiple ViewControllers. How do I access ViewControllerB directly from ViewControllerA and display it?

Should be possible, no?

Thanks!

*Translation: **Regexident***

---

> Hallo!
>
> Ich habe eine auf dem
>   NavigationController basierte App mit
>   mehreren ViewControllern. Wie kann ich
>   direkt aus dem ViewControllerA den
>   ViewControllerB aufrufen und anezigen
>   lassen? Sollte doch irgendwie gehen,
>   oder?
>
> Danke!

Edit: Please **write in english**, when posting to StackOverflow! - **Regexident**

Comment: Ok, sorry. My english ist very bad. I've seen some questions in german and thought I write in german and do not annoys the people wit my english. ;-)

Comment: Just use a spelling checker and proof read your questions and you should be fine. Writing in german (or non-english in general) however will cause your questions to be closed by moderators. Just like it happened with this one. I vetoed the close and it's reopened again now, but still.

Comment: I don't see how this is related to Xcode.

Comment: What’s the target platform: Mac OS X or iOS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. You are in `ViewController A`. It is displayed by your navigation controller. Now the only thing you need is a reference to `Viewcontroller B`.

```
[viewControllerA.navigationController pushViewController:viewControllerB animated:YES];
```